# Not able to get required XML elements using XSLT2.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

This is my XML document. I want to convert this XML document into another XML document (see required output XML section).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text1-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text2-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text3-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text4-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

         <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading3" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text2.1-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text5-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text6-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading3" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text7-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text8-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>  

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text9-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text10-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

<w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" /> 
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text11-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Text12-</w:t>
            </w:r>  
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:pict>
                    <v:shape>
                        <v:textbox>
                            <w:txbxcontent>
                                <w:p>
                                    <w:pPr>
                                        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
                                    </w:pPr>
                                    <w:r>
                                        <w:t>   
                                            Drawing Description_1
                                        </w:t>
                                    </w:r>
                                </w:p>          
                                <w:p>
                                    <w:pPr>
                                        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
                                    </w:pPr>
                                    <w:r>
                                        <w:t>   
                                            Drawing Description_2
                                        </w:t>
                                    </w:r>
                                </w:p>
                            </w:txbxcontent>
                        </v:textbox>
                    </v:shape>
                </w:pict>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>

    </w:body>
    </w:document>
```

The required **output XML** is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Document xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
    <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph>
    <Heading2>
       <Title>Text2-</Title>
       <Paragraph>Text3-</Paragraph>
       <Paragraph>Text4-</Paragraph>
       <Heading3>
          <Title>Text2.1-</Title>
       </Heading3>
    </Heading2>
    <Heading2>
       <Title>Text5-</Title>
       <Paragraph>Text6-</Paragraph>
       <Heading3>
         <Title>Text7-</Title>
         <Paragraph>Text8-</Paragraph>
       </Heading3>
   </Heading2>
   <Heading1>
      <Title>Text9-</Title>
      <Paragraph>Text10-</Paragraph>
      <Heading2>
       <Title>Text11-</Title>
         <Paragraph>Text12-</Paragraph>
         <txtContentGroup>
              <Paragraph>Drawing Description_1</Paragraph>
              <Paragraph>Drawing Description_2</Paragraph>
         </txtContentGroup>
       </Heading2>
    </Heading1>
 </Document>
```

This is my XSLT 2.0 Implementation for this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
  xmlns:user="http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356668"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs w fn mf user">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/> 

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
      <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>

      <xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">   

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
                <xsl:element name="Heading{$level}">
                <Title>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="./r/t"/>
                </Title>                

                <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level + 1)]]">
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)">
          </xsl:sequence>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
           </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="document">

    <Document>
       <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1)"/>
    </Document>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">

      <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="(./r/t)">
               <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t] | descendant::w:p[//w:r/w:t[ancestor::w:pict]][2] ">         
                       <txtContentGroup>            

                                <Paragraph>              
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./r/t"/>            
                              </Paragraph>

                              <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p">
                              </xsl:apply-templates>  

                       </txtContentGroup>          
                </xsl:when>  

                <xsl:otherwise>         
                    <Paragraph>
                       <xsl:apply-templates select="./r/t"/>
                    </Paragraph>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

      </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="descendant::w:p[not(ancestor::w:tbl)]">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p">
               </xsl:apply-templates>
             </xsl:when>     
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/r/t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it generates the following output :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Document xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
    <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph>
    <Heading2>
       <Title>Text2-</Title>
       <Paragraph>Text3-</Paragraph>
       <Paragraph>Text4-</Paragraph>
       <Heading3>
         <Title>Text2.1-</Title>
      </Heading3>
    </Heading2>
    <Heading2>
       <Title>Text5-</Title>
       <Paragraph>Text6-</Paragraph>
       <Heading3>
         <Title>Text7-</Title>
         <Paragraph>Text8-</Paragraph>
       </Heading3>
    </Heading2>
    <Heading1>
       <Title>Text9-</Title>
       <Paragraph>Text10-</Paragraph>
       <Heading2>
          <Title>Text11-</Title>
          <Paragraph>Text12-</Paragraph>
          <Paragraph>Drawing Description_1</Paragraph>
          <Paragraph>Drawing Description_2</Paragraph>
       </Heading2>
   </Heading1>
   </Document>
```

My condition is :

Whenever `<w:p>` elements contains **more than one** `descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]` in it and also that `descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]` has the ancestor of `<w:pict>` then I want to create the `<txtContentGroup>` elements and put all the `descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]` inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of input you should be using template rules, not deeply nested xsl:choose instructions. Your English statement

Whenever `<w:p>` elements contains more than one `descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]` in it and also it has the ancestor of `<w:pict>` then I want to create the `<txtContentGroup>` elements and put all the `descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]` inside it.

maps directly to the template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="w:pict//w:p[descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t][2]]">
  <textContentGroup>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]"/>
  </textContentGroup>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have Opened my Source XML file using <oXygen/> XML Editor 13.2.In that file it says the error message in <w:txbxcontent>
line and the error message is "E [Jing] elements from namespace "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" are not allowed". Please tell me whats wrong here...

Comment: @Saravanan: You were already told that what is wrong is the way the xslt code is written. You aren't using XSLT as ... XSLT but as a procedural programming language. The result is overwhelming complexity that leads to errors. If one doesn't make substantial use of XSLT templates and pattern matching, then it isn't justified at all to use XSLT -- just do the whole processing in Java or in whatever your favorite PL is.

Comment: @Saravanan If you're not going to take the advice I give you on how to move forward, you can't expect me to continue advising you.

Comment: @MichaelKay : Sorry, I didn't meant like that. Now i am following your advice by using template in my xslt2.0.And also i have the above problem when using oxygen editot.That's why i asked. I know your comments are more valuable...and also i taken your advice every time.