# How to Check following-sibling is w:tbl in my function and apply my template using xslt2.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

This is my XML document. I want to convert this XML document into another XML document (see required output XML section).I have written one function which collects all the `w:p` elements for further processing.Now, i have new requirement for process the `w:tbl` elements.So, I have written one template for process `w:tbl` elements.So, i have to check `w:tbl` elements between any `w:p` elements.If w:tbl found between any `w:p` then i want to call my template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <w:body>

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1" /> 
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text2-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>
     <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Text1-</w:t>
        </w:r>  
    </w:p>
<w:tbl>            
        <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Sachin</w:t> 
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>

            <w:tc>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Raghul</w:t> 
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc> 
        </w:tr>                 
    </w:tbl>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

My Xslt2.0 code is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
  xmlns:user="http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356668"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs w fn mf user">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/> 

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>


<xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">   

  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
      <xsl:element name="Heading{$level}">
        <Title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="./r/t"/>
        </Title>                

        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>  
    <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level + 1)]]">
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)">
      </xsl:sequence>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

 <xsl:if test="following-sibling::w:tbl">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::w:tbl"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>    
</xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="document">

    <Document>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1)"/>
    </Document>

  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:tbl">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <Paragraph>
    <xsl:value-of select="r/t"/>
  </Paragraph>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/r/t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Required output is:

```
<Document>
   <Heading1>
      <Title>Text2-</Title>
      <Paragraph>Text1-</Paragraph>
      <table>
           <Paragraph>sachin</Paragraph>
           <Paragraph>Raghul</Paragraph>
         </table>
   </Heading1>
</Document>
```

But My Generated Output is :

```
<Document xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
          xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
   <Heading1>
      <Title>Head1</Title>
      <Paragraph>para1</Paragraph>
   </Heading1>
</Document>
```

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: What issue? You've said what you are trying to do (good), but you haven't said whether it works or how it fails.

Comment: Saravanan: the example is too big and makes the chances very low that someone might have the time to digest it all. Please, *isolate* your problem and provide a *small* example, that illustrates just *this* problem. If you aren't able to provide an example with a doxen lines or so, this most probably means that you aren't able to define well the problem and to isolate it from the complete transformation. Please, analyze, extract and edit the question.

Comment: @MichaelKay : Thanks Michael Kay... I have updated my question with my generated output for your kind reference...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev:Thanks... u mean my xml file is more length or my xslt content is...Could i know that...

Comment: @Saravanan: The source XML document can be a bout dozen lines. It needn't be the same (big) document you are really working with. It could be just 10 `<num>` elements with different values (such as 0 to 9), and you can say: I want to process all `num` element starting from one selected in `$start` and ending in one selected in `$end`. This is the problem you are interested with, so a bigger and more complex-structured XML document must not be given, as this distracts from the real problem. When you get a solution, then you'll apply it in processing your real XML document.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev : I already cut out lot of irrelevant elements from the documents i am working with.I couldn't able to remove any elements from my question.I am really sorry for this...Can you help me with this?.. I have also put the my xslt transformation generated output for your reference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"
  xmlns:user="http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356668"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs w fn mf user">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/> 

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="paragraphs" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>


<xsl:for-each-group select="$paragraphs" group-starting-with="p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">   

  <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level)]">
      <xsl:element name="Heading{$level}">
        <Title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="./r/t"/>
        </Title>                

        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>  
    <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::p[pPr/pStyle/@w:val = concat('Heading', $level + 1)]]">
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)">
      </xsl:sequence>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

 <xsl:if test="following-sibling::w:tbl">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::w:tbl"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>    
</xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="document">

    <Document>
      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1)"/>
    </Document>

  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:tbl">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="descendant::w:p[w:r/w:t]"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <Paragraph>
    <xsl:value-of select="r/t"/>
  </Paragraph>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/r/t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```